# What type annotations are required for Petgraph's all_simple_paths() function?

Tags: rust, petgraph

I'm trying to use Petgraph's [`all_simple_paths()`](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.5.1/petgraph/algo/fn.all_simple_paths.html), but I'm not sure what type annotations are required, the the docs don't give an example. It returns a `impl Iterator<Item = TargetColl>` where `TargetColl: FromIterator<G::NodeId>`, but I don't know what sort of annotation I should make for that.

```
for path in algo::all_simple_paths(&graph, x, y, 0, None) {}
```

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
   --> lib.rs:10:29
   |
10 | for path in algo::all_simple_paths(&graph, x, y, 0, None) {}
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the element type for this iterator is not specified
```

Comment: Try putting `let path: Vec<YourNodeId> = path` inside your loop.

Answer (score 1):

It should be enough to use

```rust
for path in algo::all_simple_paths::<Vec<_>, _>(&graph, x, y, 0, None) {}
```

Here's a working example:

```rust
use petgraph::{algo, prelude::*};

fn main() {
    let mut graph = DiGraph::<&str, i32>::new();

    let a = graph.add_node("a");
    let b = graph.add_node("b");
    let c = graph.add_node("c");
    let d = graph.add_node("d");

    graph.extend_with_edges(&[
        (a, b, 1),
        (b, c, 1),
        (c, d, 1),
        (a, b, 1),
        (b, d, 1),
    ]);

    let ways = algo::all_simple_paths::<Vec<_>, _>(&graph, a, d, 0, None)
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    assert_eq!(4, ways.len());
}
```